# How to debug ASP.Net MVC in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was hunting a phantom-problem, until I recognized that the debugging wasn't working as expected.

I tried to debug some controller-code (c#) in my ASP.Net application and for this, I stopped the excecution, using a breakpoint (F9).

I started debugging with F5 and the code stopped, as expected at the breakpoint.
There, I tried to fetch some data, using different approaches. 
None of the tries gave me the expected result so after a while, I recognized, that with every excecution the same compiled code is used and not the code, I was watching (and changing) in the editor.

I'm pretty sure, that in VS2017 it worked that way, so I could change the code while excecution.
How can I debug the C# code (and change the code) while excecution?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Visual Studio 2019? I know my version of 2019 lets you debug and change code while it's executing. On Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.4.5

Comment: Did you modify the executed code while hitting the breakpoint? When you modify the code after the breakpoint, the debugger could execute the modified code. But when you modified code before breakpoint, the debugger will ignore it.

Comment: Thanks guys, the solution was a wrong option (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Vs2019 by In Tools > Options > (or Debug > Options) > Debugging > General, select Edit and Continue in the right pane.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Prany. That was the solution.